# vue js variable to laravel eloquent model in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

i have tried to pass attribute_id in eloquent query here attribute_id is vue js variable. but it is giving error 
Use of undefined constant attribute_id - assumed 'attribute_id'

```
<div v-for='(attribute_list, attribute_id) in combination' class="col-md-2">

   <div class="text-center"> <label>{!! \App\Attribute::findOrFail(attribute_id)->attribute_name !!} 
    </label> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, I don't think you can mix javascript and php variables by any means. The workaround might be using a session variable.

Or,

You could make a controller to find the attribute.
Then, you could simply use axios to perform the get request:

```
            axios.get('url')
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success                   
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                return error.data;
            })
```

and then set the value in the DOM.